# How to count seconds programatically in C#?

Tags: c#, time

Actually I want to display 3 images only one at a time, but it should change for every 10 secs. For that I need to count seconds. Is there any predefined Class for this requirement?

Comment: Checkout `Timer` and it's events

Comment: my requirement is on a webpage i have to display image one by one without timer control,i need to do this by using complete code only .

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

timer.Elapsed += OnChangePictureEvent;

private static void OnChangePicture(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change picture code
}
```

Comment: A `Timer` class, yes.  That one, no.  It's not designed for interacting with UI.

Comment: There's one that's specifically for use with WinForms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called `Timer`.

Actually, there's more than one.  You should use the one that matches your image display code.  For example, [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if your image UI is WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, while `Timer` fits this bill more specifically, there is also the [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for when you need to count seconds directly.